# Hyperledger Cello Operator Dashboard keeps loading

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-cello

I am facing an issue with Hyperledger fabric cello.

When I try to open `operator dashboard` on `localhost:8080` it keeps loading. However `user dashboard` on `localhost:8081` quickly opens.

`localhost:8080` keeps loading and shows `waiting for localhost...` at the bottom.

I tried the master installation and worker installation.

I tried `make all` also but still it does not work.

I followed the tutorial from their official tutorial website 
http://hyperledger-cello.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/

I am trying to fix this from last 2 days but no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Update:

I am using the following versions:

1. Docker: Docker version 18.03.1-ce, build 9ee9f40
2. Docker-Compose: docker-compose version 1.21.2, build a133471

logs for `make start` command:

```
$ sudo make start
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/akshay/cello'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/akshay/cello'
echo "Start all services... docker images must exist local now, otherwise, run 'make setup-master first' !"
Start all services... docker images must exist local now, otherwise, run 'make setup-master first' !
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d --no-recreate
WARNING: The WEBROOT variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: Some services (mongo) use the 'deploy' key, which will be ignored. Compose does not support 'deploy' configuration - use `docker stack deploy` to deploy to a swarm.
Creating network "cello_default" with the default driver
Creating cello-watchdog           ... done
Creating cello-engine             ... done
Creating cello-mongo              ... done
Creating cello_nfs_1              ... done
Creating cello-dashboard_mongo    ... done
Creating cello-operator-dashboard ... done
Creating cello-user-dashboard     ... done
```

Answer (score 0):

I've recently stumbled past this problem, but I cannot reproduce it, and I'm unsure what exactly fixed it, I can try my best to help though!

Did you install the images? If not it may be worth reinstalling them.

```
$ sudo su
$ cd cello
$ make stop    
$ make dockerhub-pull   
$ make start
```

Reboot your machine and try again. I honestly just went back through the guide @ https://cello.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup_master/ with a fine tooth comb.